# Positiv or Negative value depends on relationship - Possible to SELECT SUM(...) in single statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

Each row in the `assets` table contains the fields `value` and `type`. The `type` field is a relation ship to the `types` table where each row has a field `is_negative`:

```
// assets
id  |  value  |  type
----------------------
 1  |   10    |   1
 2  |    4    |   2
 3  |    1    |   NULL


// types   
id  |  is_negative  
------------------
 1  |    0    
 2  |    1
```

I would like to query the sum of all asset values where the type specifies whether the value is negative or positive. Assets with no type should have a negative value.

In the above example the result should be `10 - 4 - 1 = 5`

Is this somehow possible within a single `SELECT SUM(value)...` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tricky way (avoiding conditions):

```
select sum( value * (0.5 - coalesce(t.is_negative, 1)) * 2 )
from assets a
left join types t on t.id = a.type
```

Another way (more readable):

```
select sum(value * case when not is_negative then 1 else -1 end)
from assets a
left join types t on t.id = a.type;
```

Comment: See what you did there... Nice :-)

Comment: @Strawberry I don't like conditions ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, quite easily.

```
SELECT SUM(IF(is_negative = 1 OR is_negative IS NULL, value * -1, value))
FROM assets a
LEFT JOIN types t ON a.type = t.id
```

Answer (score 2):

...or very similarly...

```
 SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN COALESCE(is_negative,1)= 1 THEN value * -1 ELSE value END) x 
   FROM assets x 
   LEFT 
   JOIN types y
     ON y.id = x.type;
```